# How to prevent event bubbling for custom events in a Backbone application?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have two views - ItemView and CardView -

In card view, I trigger a global event of ItemView as -

```
self.eventBus.trigger('dragEvent', {
       toId: moveToId,
       fromId: moveFromId,
       id: itemId,
       e: event
       });
```

This event trigger is handled by 'onDragEvent' function in ItemView as-

```
onDragEvent:  function(options) {
   ...     
 }
```

The *dragEvent* is bubbling up. How do I avoid it?

Comment: I don't think you stop event propagation without replacing or wrapping `trigger`. Backbone events don't really bubble like browser events, they get sent to everyone that is listening and that's that.

Comment: Where did you trigger the dragEvent event ?

Answer (score 1):

@muistooshort may be correct when it comes to triggering an `Event` module like that. However, you can stop a `View` event from bubbling with `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`